# onmouseover change text based on value from database

Tags: c#, jquery, onmouseover

My code is in C#. I have a span with id `change`. I need to change the text `onmouseover` to a value from the database. I got the value and assign it to a label and I made it hidden. Now on mouseover I want to get the value of the hidden label.

Here is my script.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

  $("#change").mouseover(function () {
      $('#change').text("value of label");


});
$("#change").mouseout(function () {
    $('#change').text("Investor");
});
});


</script>
```

How can I do it?

**Solved By Me :)**

I have solved the issue. It was because I had visible=false in the label properties and I should replace it with style="display:none;" .
  .Regarding my Script. It is as below .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var originalText = $('#change').text();

    $('#change').mouseover(function () {
        var hiddenVar = $('[id$="NewAccountsLabel"]').html();
        $('#change').text(hiddenVar);
    });


    $('#change').mouseleave(function () {
        $('#change').text(originalText);
    });
```

});

Comment: What is the id of your another label where you are storing the value from database?

Comment: NewAccountsLabel @PriyankPanchal

Comment: So, have you tried doing `$('#change').text($('#NewAccountsLabel').text());` on your mouseover event?

Comment: The word Investor disappear and it shows nothing @PriyankPanchal

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the label value , your label should have the id

$(document).ready(function () {

Var lblvalue = $('#label').val();

$("#change").mouseover(function () {

```
  $('#change').text(lblvalue);
```

});

$("#change").mouseout(function () {

```
$('#change').text("Investor");
```

});

Comment: What is your label Id?

Comment: NewAccountsLabel

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery events are `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events. More on this [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/)

```js
// save the previous value in javascript variable
var originalText = $('#change').text();

//mouse event on mouseover the span
$('#change').mouseover(function() {

  // read the value from the hidden label
  var hiddenVar = $('#NewAccountsLabel').text();

  // assign the new value from the hidden var
  $('#change').text(hiddenVar);

});

//mouse event when mouse leaves the span
$('#change').mouseleave(function() {
  // assign the original value when it leaves
  $('#change').text(originalText);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="change"> Investor</span>
<label id='NewAccountsLabel' hidden> value from DB </label>
```

Comment: Is the code snippet executes correctly in your browser ? You can run it using "Run code Snippet" button

Comment: yes It is working fine. but my code is not working. from the code behind I do NewAccountsLabel.Text = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString(); . And I got the value. so I made it hidden. but my javascript gives me empty value on mouseover. It just make Investor word disappear.

Comment: Your NewAccountsLabel is serverside Id of the label. What we need is client side Id that we can use in jquery. Could you please share your complete code including HTML and any server code?

Comment: i cannot send me complete code. but here is the following               <span id="change">Investor</span> 

    <asp:Label ID="NewAccountsLabel" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>  please help me on getting the client side id of my label. @PriyankPanchal

Comment: i tried this var x = document.getElementById('<%= NewAccountsLabel.ClientID %>').value; and var x = document.getElementById('<%= NewAccountsLabel.ClientID %>'); but they are not working @PriyankPanchal

Comment: @karthickj25 i tried this var x = document.getElementById('<%= NewAccountsLabel.ClientID %>').value; and var x = document.getElementById('<%= NewAccountsLabel.ClientID %>'); but they are not working

Comment: @Arwa can you try    `var x = $('#<%= NewAccountsLabel.ClientID %>').text(); `

Comment: It shows empty :( It seems it is not getting the value @karthickj25

Comment: I have solved the issue. It was because I had visible=false and I should replace it with the style as below.
<asp:Label ID="NewAccountsLabel" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:Label>   and regarding my JavaScript var. It is as below . 
            var hiddenVar = $('[id$="NewAccountsLabel"]').html();
    Thanking you all and really appreciate it.

Comment: Good to  know... another approach is to use the viewstate, you can assign the hidden variable value in viewstate and read it in client side javascript. you can refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx) for more info